# Objects of the same name in base and derived class not getting flagged as an error

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Base
{
public:
 type1 m_Pants;
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:
 type2 m_Pants
};
```

This essentially didn't get flagged as an error, but was creating all kinds of clobbering and issues throughout a project.

Does anyone know of a technicality that wouldn't flag this?

Answer (score 10):

It isn't getting flagged as an error because it's not an error.  There's nothing that says you can't have members in a derived class that are named the same as members in a base class.

If you have an object `obj` of type `Derived`, then `obj.m_Pants` refers to the `m_Pants` in `Derived`.  If you want to refer to the base member, you can do so using `obj.Base::m_Pants`.

If you are in a member function of `Base` or have a `Base*` that points to an object of type `Derived`, then `m_Pants` always refers to the member of `Base`, because in those contexts there is no knowledge of the class `Derived` and its members.

Well, it's not a code error; it's almost certainly a design error.

Comment: I've tried `int val = obj.Base::m_Pants` in C++Builder6 and got compilation error: **E2247 'Base::m_Pants' is not accessible** (m_Pants is public)

Comment: It compiles only with get/set funcs `public: int getBase(){ return Base::m_Pants}`

Comment: @Alexander:  Well, in the example code, `Derived` inherits privately from `Base`, so, you're right that that wouldn't work.  You'd need to change it to inherit publicly.

Comment: Although it wasn't exactly 'm_Pants', the name used was extremely general and apparently very popular.

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly what it's supposed to do.  The derived shadows the base.

Comment: Functions can be overloaded and overridden.  Members cannot.  `Derived::m_pants` and `Base::m_pants` are two different variables completely.  If you use `std::cout << sizeof (Base) << ' ' << sizeof (Derived) << std::endl;` in a small test program, you would see that `Derived` is larger in size than `Base`.  You could even make the variables use the same name and type, but they're still different variables because they belong to different classes.

Comment: Ah, you changed the term you used from "overrides" to "shadows", thus invalidating my comment.  Thanks for fixing it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

One variable is shadowing the other. It's just like if you declared a member variable name `x` and then had a member function which declared its own `x`, except that here, one of the variables is in the base class and one is in a derived class.

```
int func(int x)
{
    return x;
}
```

would return the value of `x` you passed in, not that of the member variable `x`. One variable "shadows" the other. It's why it's a good idea to name your variables so that they don't ever have names which could clash.