# C++ generate a warning when a class member shadow a class member of its parent?

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there a way to generate a warning when a derived class member variable name shadows one of its parents class, e.g

```
class Mother 
{
public:
  Mother() : i(0) {}
  virtual ~Mother() {}
protected:
  int i;
};

class Child : public Mother
{
public:
  Child() : Mother(), i(0) {}
  virtual ~Child() {}
protected:
  int i; /* NOK Expecting warning : declaration of 'int Child::i' shadows 'int Mother::i' */
};
```

Above code generates no warning when compiled with `-Wshadow` with g++.

Comment: Why should it warn you? It was meant to be overriden by a child class that's why it's marked as virtual.

Comment: No, he's referring to the `i` member variable in the protected area.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769925/objects-of-the-same-name-in-base-and-derived-class-not-getting-flagged-as-an-err

Comment: I think about 20 years ago g++ used to warn, at least about shadowing function definitions (which may be due to a lacking ` virtual`  in the base class which the derived class is not aware of).

Answer (score 2):

I actually saw code as follows which shows the necessity of the shadow warnings.

```
int val = 0;

if (flag == aval) 
  int val = firstval;
else if (flag == bval)
  int val = secondval;
else if
.
.
.

switch (val)
{

// put cases here

}
```

I have also seen shadow warnings where the inside variable was meant to be local, have no effect on the outside variable, and the shadowed variable was not supposed to be referenced. Actually, it was easier to just change the name to prevent the warning.

Answer (score 2):

In my tests, `gcc` 7.4.0 indeed does not show a warning for this with `-Wshadow` (nor with other `-Wshadow*` flags, and [current documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) does not tell about this possibility.

However `clang` 6.0.0 has the option `-Wshadow-field` (included in `-Wshadow-all`) which gives on your code:

> main.cxx:43:7: warning: non-static data member 'i' of 'Child' shadows member inherited from type 'Mother' [-Wshadow-field]
>
> int i; /* NOK Expecting warning : declaration of 'int Child::i' shadows 'int Mother::i' */
>
> main.cxx:34:7: note: declared here

Answer (score -5):

This will not show a warning because this is allowed. It is possible because *"at most one of the one of the names is actually defined in that scope; others would be merely visible in that scope. Name resolution rules determine which name is chosen, if there are multiple candidates...You really do not want to give a warning for every case where the compiler picks between alternatives."* - [@MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964019/195488).

Comment: Well, with _all_ shadow warnings, the compiler has a deterministic rule to pick one of the choices. How is this different?

Comment: Compilers warn about many things that are allowed; when something is not allowed, the compiler generates errors, not warnings. Warnings are there to indicate that you might have done something you did not intended.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Because its not ambiguous.

Comment: In my experience, shadowing is almost always a programming error. There are a few exceptions here and there, like MacOS having global stuff like "Line" that will trigger shadow-warnings for variables of that name, but on gcc I have -Wshadow (and I have -Werror anyway) among the huge list of warnings (clang++ and Visual C++ are easier to set up :-)). Personally, I would even vote for a change that forces you to place "override" on everything that should, well, override something else, even if it's just one "i" shadowing another "i" in nested loops.

Comment: From my point of view,  the compiler should warn you when you write probably erroneous code. Like Luc said, warnings are about things that are allowed by probably not intended.

Comment: @0A0D Neither `std::string message; if(test()) { std::string message = "test succeed";} else { std::string message = "test failed";} std::cout<<message;` but then compiler warn you. BTW could you tell me one case where shadowing attributes can be intended?

Comment: @Christian Go get an idea of good designs which don't end up with 'i' or 'a' in some mission-critical inheritance tree instead. C++ is not supposed to teach you how to program bad designs. There are others for this.

Comment: You got one of my rare downvotes.  "This will not show a warning because this is allowed" is an incorrect argument.  If you do something that is not _allowed_ you get an _error_;  if you do something _allowed_ but probably inadvisable you get a _warning_.

Comment: @ChristianStieber:  you are completely correct.  There is never any reason to shadow variables - there's always a better way to do it; and conversely, shadowing variables is responsible for a lot of subtle bugs that are very hard to find by reading the code.  I have no idea what ActiveTrayPrntrTagDataStrDrvr is trying to say...

Comment: @0A0D: Your argument is incorrect: "This will not show a warning because this is allowed."  Warnings are for cases that are _allowed_ but _inadvisable._   If the statement were not allowed, you would get an _error._  This has been explained to you by three different people, so I suspect it's not just that I don't write clearly...

Comment: Actually there is a gcc warning for virtual functions that can be switched on: -Wsuggest-override
Warn about overriding virtual functions that are not marked with the override keyword.