# VC++: Prevent duplicated member variable name declaration in derived class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to refactor and rewrite some parts of a legacy library. This library has base classes with same variable names repeatedly declared and used in derived classes (caused by copy/paste programming). For example I have:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
public:
  int m_nVar;

protected:
  virtual void MyFunc()
     {
       m_nVar++;
     }
 public:
   MyBaseClass()
    {
      m_nVar = 1;
    }
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass
{
public:
   int m_nVar;
protected:
  virtual void MyFunc()
     {
       m_nVar++;
     }
 public:
   MyDerivedClass ()
    {
      m_nVar = 2;
    }
};
```

This situation causes me problems because I need to move some functionality I need to a more general base class so that *MyBaseClass* can be derived from it.

```
class MyNewBaseClass
{
public:
  int m_nVar;

protected:
  virtual void MyFunc()
     {
       m_nVar++;
     }
 public:
   MyNewBaseClass()
    {
    }
};

class MyBaseClass : public MyNewBaseClass
{
 public:
   MyBaseClass()
    {
      m_nVar = 1;
    }
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass
{
public:
   int m_nVar;//this causes me problems, I need to get notifications on occurrences of such situations 
 public:
   MyDerivedClass ()
    {
      m_nVar = 2; //this assignments has no effect on MyNewBaseClass::m_nVar
    }
};
```

After I make my modifications *MyFunc()* in a *MyDerivedClass* instance does not work as the original code (first run on original causes *m_nVar = 3*, but in my modified code it becomes *m_nVar = 2*).

I need some kind of compiler error or warning to notify me of all occurrences of such situations or any other solutions to accomplish what I need.

What do you suggest which works in Visual Studio (VC++)?

Comment: I don't really see the problem. If the member variables are `private` they are separate. `MyBaseClass::m_nVar` is a distinct and different member variable from `MyDerivedClass::m_nVar`. Whenever a function in `MyBaseClass` refers to `m_nVar` it is `MyBaseClass::m_nVar` that's used, it can never be `MyDerivedClass::m_nVar`.

Comment: First of all these variables are mostly protected or public. I need to move some duplicated methods to my base class which are using this variables. So I declare m_nVar in my new base class and remove it from  MyBaseClass. When I try to test this method I notice it is not working in MyDerivedClass  because it did not properly assigned. So I find out it is redeclared in MyDerivedClass  and needs to be removed from there too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ generate a warning when a class member shadow a class member of its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521989/c-generate-a-warning-when-a-class-member-shadow-a-class-member-of-its-parent)