# warning on derived class member shadowing base class member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, compiler-warnings, clang++

C++ compilers warn when a local variable shadows another variable.
e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/TYYf8F

However none of the major C++ compilers warn when a member of a derived class shadows a member of the base class:

```
class A
{
    int _memberVar = 2;

  public:
    virtual int memberVar()
    {
        return _memberVar;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    int _memberVar = 3;
};

int main()
{
    A* pB = new B();
    return pB->memberVar(); // returns 2
}
```

see https://godbolt.org/g/fBMUAd

Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: OK, so B contains both members, why does this eliminate the need for a warning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ generate a warning when a class member shadow a class member of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521989/c-generate-a-warning-when-a-class-member-shadow-a-class-member-of-its-parent)

Comment: @alain Thanks. I swear I searched for it before asking. Still there's seems to be no answer. :-(

Answer (score -2):

Virtual is a mechanism in the caller of a function to decide which function to call.  It does not make the function to somehow behave "virtual".  Since you did not overwrite the function B::memberVar() it is still calling A::memberVar(), and this behaves as any other member function of A.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't ask about the behaviour but about the lack of warnings.