# how does the 'this' pointer work in inheritance in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, this, vtable

questions:

1. in the code below, the 'this' pointer points to different things in base and derived classes, even though it technically contains the same address. why is that.
2. what is happening when the 'this' pointer is used with inheritance.
   (any help would be appreciated. thanks.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// this pointer and inheritance.
class base {
public:
  int x;
  base() {
    x = 10;
  }
  void func() {
    cout<< this->x << endl; // 10
    cout<< this << endl;
  }
};
class derived : public base {
public:
  int x;
  derived() {
    x = 20;
  }
  void func() {
    cout<< this->x << endl; // 20
    cout<< this << endl;
    base::func();
  }
};

int main () {
  derived d;
  d.func();

  cout<< "execution complete.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

```
output:
20
0x61ff18
10
0x61ff18
execution complete.
```

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410120/warning-on-derived-class-member-shadowing-base-class-member

Comment: `derived` has 2 `x` here.

Comment: 1. it points to the same thing, the instance `derived d;` in your `main`; then you see 10 and 20, because your `int x;` is shadowed in the derived class; 2. nothing special

Comment: `struct x {int y;}; x z;` // &z and &z.y are the same address but point to different things

Comment: Both questions "How does the 'this' pointer work?" and "What is happening when the 'this' pointer is used?" are probably too broad for Stack Overflow.  It seems that your understanding is incomplete, and you are trying to ask us to explain aspects of C++ until your understanding feels sufficiently complete.  I think what's needed is a more specific question.

Comment: In your code a `derived` IS - from a design perspective - a `base`, and that translates to meaning a `derived *` IS a `base *` (although the reverse is not true).   Printing `this` as you are converts it to `void *`, which is the address in memory - and (in your case) that address is for the first byte in memory of your object.  Since, in your example, the `this` pointers are both for the same object, printing them gives the same address.   [A tougher thing to explain would be what happens if your derived class has multiple bases - in that case, what happens is compiler dependent].

Comment: The real question is: How does `this` work with multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. in the code below, the 'this' pointer points to different things in base and derived classes, even though it technically contains the same address. why is that.

Classes contain subobjects. They can be base-subobjects or non-static data members. The first sub-object can share the memory address of the encapsulating complete object:

```
|derived  |  < complete object
|base|x   |  < sub objects of derived
|x   |       < sub objects of base sub object

^
|
same address
```

> 2. what is happening when the 'this' pointer is used with inheritance.

If you call a non-static member function of a class, `this` points to the instance argument within that function.

If you call a non-virtual non-static member function of a base of a derived object, `this` will point to the base sub object within that function.

If you call a virtual non-static member function of a class using unqualified lookup, it will call the most derived override of that function and `this` within that function will point to the object where that function is derived.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `derived` contains **two integers**.  They have the names:

```
this->base::x
```

and

```
this->derived::x
```

What you seem to be discovering is that you can simply type `this->x` to refer to one of those integers.

The compiler will decide which `x` you are referring to by context.  Inside the `base` class, you must mean `this->base::x`.  Inside the derived class, it is assumed that you mean `this->derived::x` and you would need to explicitly write `this->base::x` to tell the compiler that you are referring to the `int x;` defined in `base`.

> the 'this' pointer points to different things in base and derived classes

That is not true.

`this` does not point to different things in `base` and `derived`.  It is the same `this`.

The meaning of `this->x` changes, because your class has two variables both named `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The `derived` class in your program has a member function named `func` that **hides** the inherited member function with the same name from `base`. Similarly, the `derived` class also a data member named `x` that **hides** the inherited data member with the same name from `base`.

Now, when you wrote:

```
d.func(); //this calls the derived class member function `func` implicitly passing the address of `d` to the implicit `this` parameter
```

In the above call, you're calling the `derived` class' member function `func` meanwhile implicitly passing the address of `d` to the implicit `this` parameter. The type of `this` inside `func` of `derived` is `derived*`.

Now, inside the member function `func` of `derived` the expression `this->x` uses the data member `x` of the derived class(and not the inherited member `x`) because as explained above, it hides the inherited member from base. Thus **we get the output** `20`.

Next, `cout<< this << endl;` just prints `this`.

Next, the *call expression* `base::func()` is encountered. Also note that `base::func()` is equivalent to writing `this->base::func()`. This has the effect that it calls the inherited member function named `func` that was hidden due to the derived class having a function with the same name. Note in this call also, the same address is passed to the implicit `this` parameter of `func` of base class. The difference this time is that, `this` inside `base`'s member function `func` is of type `base*`.

Now, inside the member function `func` of `base`, the `x` in the expression `this->x` refers to the base class' data member `x` and hence prints the value `10`. Thus **we get the output** `10`.

Finally, we have `cout<< this << endl;` inside `base`'s member function `func`, which just prints the `this`.